# Reducing KKT system

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I was using CVXOPT library to solve one of my quadratic programming problem. I found that, CVXOPT library solves KKT system efficiently by reducing a 3x3 matrox into 2x2 blocks which has the following form:

$$
 \begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
    \begin{bmatrix}
     P & A^\mathsf{T} & G^\mathsf{T}\\
     A & 0 & 0\\
     G & 0 & -W^\mathsf{T}W
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
     x\\
     y\\
     z
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
     b_x\\
     b_y\\
     b_z
    \end{bmatrix}
   \end{aligned}
   \label{eqn:KKT_solution_1}
  \end{equation}
$$

This is transformed into:
$$
 \begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
    \begin{bmatrix}
     P+G^\mathsf{T}W^{-1}W^\mathsf{-T}G & A^\mathsf{T}\\
     A & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
     x\\
     y
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
     b_x+G^\mathsf{T}W^{-1}W^\mathsf{-T}b_z\\
     b_y
    \end{bmatrix}
   \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}  
$$

My question is, in which condition this is true. I have read their [Documentation](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/coneprog.pdf). They have not provided proper reference in this case. Can some please explain how can we write such reduction? Or any reference? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true as long as $W^{-1}$ exists. Just solve the last equation for $z$ and substitute it into the first one.

P.S. For non-square $W$: it is true when $M=W^TW$ is invertible, but $W^{-1}W^{-T}$ above has to be replaced with $M^{-1}$.

**Edit:**

With the notation $M=W^TW$, the last equation is 
$$
Gx-Mz=b_z\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad z=M^{-1}(Gx-b_z).
$$
Substitute it into the first one
$$
Px+A^Ty+G^Tz=b_x\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad Px+A^Ty+G^TM^{-1}(Gx-b_z)=b_x
$$
which after rearranging becomes exactly the new first equation
$$
(P+G^TM^{-1}G)x+A^Ty=b_x+G^TM^{-1}b_z.
$$

**Example:**

Assume that you have the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\5\\6
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is equivalent to three equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
x+2y+3z&=&4\\
2x&=&5\\
3x+z&=&6.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Let us rewrite the last equation as $z=6-3x$ and substitute it into the first one. Then the variable $z$ is eliminated, and we have only two equations left
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
x+2y+3(6-3x)&=&4\\
2x&=&5.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
After rearranging the first equation, the system looks like
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
x-9x+2y+18&=&4\\
2x&=&5
\end{array}
\right.\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
-8x+2y&=&-14\\
2x&=&5
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which corresponds to the $2\times 2$ matrix equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-8 & 2\\
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-14\\5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Hi, I have just edited it. Thank you for pointing out. Can you please give the reference why and how we can reduce 3x3 matrices into 2x2 matrices?

Comment: I have done some editing too how you can reduce it.

Comment: I am sorry for my less understanding. Will you please make it bit more elaborate if possible?

Comment: I am not sure how to make it more elaborate. Maybe you can explain what part does not look clear to you? All this is just a basic linear algebra.

Comment: I mean, I want to know the background of reducing 3x3 system to 2x2. I am not good in mathematics, but trying to learn by myself.

Comment: Ok. I will add an example.

Comment: That will be really great!

Comment: That is really awesome, this is more than clear. I have done all these things in school mathematics but unconsciously. Your solution is really helpful.